# Rows and columns of button won't fit mobile screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make my buttons fit the mobile screen, but for some reason, it looks bad.
The background won't continue down. Can you point me where I was wrong?
The div of buttons is inside a form if it helps.
I am using rows, and then 3 col-md-4, I think its something my body or container problem. but could not find the problem.

Computer look :[image]
Mobile look:[image]

**Html Code**

```
<div id="studentclass" style="display: none">

<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="4" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב1
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="5" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 2
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="6" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="7" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ג 1
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="8" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 classbutton">
        <button value="9" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>


.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {


    .classbuttonsize {
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
    }

    #studentclass .row {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #studentclass .classbutton {
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
    }
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

}

.container > div {
    margin: auto;
}


body {

    background-image: url('{% static ' images/background.jpg ' %}');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}


.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.classbutton {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.classbuttonsize {
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Fixed it:

just add to the div of col:

```
 <div class="col-4 classbutton" style="width: 33%; height: 33%">
```

Comment: now width and height will be same on all screen with this style="width: 33%; height: 33%"

Answer (score 1):

change the structure if using bootstrap 4

```css
.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.classbutton{
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {


    .classbuttonsize {
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
            
    }

    #studentclass .row {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #studentclass .classbutton {
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
    }
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<div id="studentclass" style="display: block">

<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="4" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב1
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="5" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 2
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="6" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="7" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ג 1
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="8" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 classbutton">
        <button value="9" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ב 3
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: now in every row there is 3, but they are on top of other how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<div class="col-sm-4 classbutton">
        <button value="7" type="button" class="btn classbuttonsize btn-primary btn-lg">ג 1
        </button>
 </div>`